# Can you check the field in current Workflow Tasks List and also check a field in the Pages Library?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint Designer 2007, I would like to build a workflow attached on "Workflow Tasks" list,

which trigger when item is created and item is changed.

Then, in workflow Conditions, is it possible to check the field in current Workflow Tasks List AND field in Pages Library?

e.g: check "Assigned to" equal Approvers Group, and check Approval Status & Version in Pages Library.

Do reply if need further clarification, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. In your conditions dropdown (in the new Workflow Wizard), choose "Compare any datasource"
2. Click the first value link, then the little function button (fx)
3. Choose the source as the Target list (Pages Library) - the lookup definition window will expand
4. Choose Version for the Field in the Lookup Details section
5. Choose List:ID (Pages:ID) for the Field in the Find the List Item section
6. Press the function button (fx) next to Value in the Find the List Item section
7. Source = Current Item
8. Field = Workflow Item ID

Putting a workflow on the workflow tasks list is totally possible, but seems like a very bad idea since it could lead to an infinite loop.  So if you do this make the first step a check to see if the current item Workflow Name equals this workflow's name.  If so, exit the workflow.